# Delegating touch events

Tags: android, events, delegates, touch

lets assume i have a LinearLayout , horizontal that contains a TextView and afterward a Spinner or another clicable TextView or an EditText.

I want that a click on any part of the line (if the layout has padding then the layout area as well!) will deleage the onTouchEvent to the Right part of the layout (EditText, TextView or Spinner) as if they were clicked themselves.

Doing it myself will require me either create my own versions of those widgets (too much work for little effect :-( ) or putting listeners on many items for the touch events and delegate them. I'm pretty sure Android has some methods or properties to do that, just didn't see any so far.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar to this a while back, and ended up writing my own delegate and assigning the onclicklisteners for all of the components in my layout to that delegate. It's cumbersome, but not too painful to implement, and it turned out well.

Point being, I didn't see anything in the API to handle that sort of thing. The only other thing I might offer is that it is certainly possible to assign an onclicklistener to a component and simply send the event to another component's onclicklistener like so:

```
thislinearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getOtherComponent().performClick();
    }
});
```

You can do the same thing with touch listeners.

Comment: 10x for the reply! (the only one:-))
It is possible what you suggest but specifically for touch events i discovered touchDelegates, if you take a look in the View class source code you'll see that it first checks mTouchDelegate for nullity, if it's not (if you set it to not null) it will delegate the touch event, i do belive onClick will be called AFTER a touch event so it should perform the click as well.
10x!

Comment: Hm....that may be something to look at ;-) You're right, onClick is called after the system determines the touch event is a click, and not something else like a drag. Good luck!